# Not able to execute a url from python script running via Cron - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-3.5

```
import Datetime
import webbrowser
import os
import time

n = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

fo = open("Morning.py","r")

if n == 0:

    print('Monday')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com',new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('pkill chromium')

if n == 1:

    print('Monday')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com',new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('pkill chromium')

if n == 2:

    print('Monday')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com',new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('pkill chromium')

if n == 3:

    print('Monday')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com',new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('pkill chromium')

if n == 4:

    print('Monday')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com',new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('pkill chromium')

if n == 5:

    print('Monday')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com',new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('pkill chromium')

if n == 6:

    print('Monday')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com',new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('pkill chromium')

os.system('pkill chromium')

print('Finish')

fo.close()

Python3 - file executes fine but if I want to schedule to run this code to run every minute, I am using Cron (rasberry pi)

* * * * * cd Desktop && /usr/bin/python3.5m Morning.py >> Output.out
```

I can see my code executes but chronium browser will not open. Can any of you help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. Your job fails because it requires an [X session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), since you're trying to open a web browser. You should place `export DISPLAY=:0;` after the schedule in your cronjob, as in

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; cd Desktop && /usr/bin/python3.5m Morning.py >> Output.out
```

But note that `cd Desktop && /usr/bin/python3.5m Morning.py` might also not work with `cron`. It is advised to just put multiple commands into a `.sh` script that has been `chmod +x`'d.

If this doesn't work, you could replace `:0` with the output of `echo $DISPLAY` in a graphical terminal.